# scratchbox cross compilation for android

Tags: android, cross-compiling

How to we setup scratchbox for android to do cross compilation?What type of target do we choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used the following link: http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/scratchbox-on-ubuntu/
 except that i used a different target.